# DocuSignEnvelopeInformation null using XmlSerializerFormat

Tags: docusignapi

My DocuSign Connect Listener cannot deserialize the XML it's receiving. The Envelope is always null. I have decorated both my class and it's interface with the [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")] and decorated the Operation Contract with XmlSerializerFormat. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/, that is not a valid url.

**Answer**

In my listeners I use a suitable XML library (platform/stack specific) to pull values and documents out of the notification messages.

These days, there are often XML libraries that are more convenient than the standard [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) and its various wrappers. For example, [BeautifulSoup for Python](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

You can see working examples of a DocuSign Connect/eventNotification listener in various languages and stacks:

- [Java](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java)
- [Node JS](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-node)
- [C#](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp)
- [PHP](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-php)
- [Python](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-python)

Also, check out the [webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) for more information.

Debugging, the logging facility for the connect messages is also very helpful. See the DocuSign Admin panel, the "Integrations" section, the "Connect" item for access to the logs.